# Is it practical to use "shared"/"dynamic" in cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Once i change ~/.cabal/config as below, i cannot (re)install many packages.

```
shared: True
executable-dynamic: True
```

Please shed a light on me.

thanks!

Comment: Did you try `cabal-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know if this is the case here, but it's common with other such cabal flags that after you do this, you must manually reinstall all your packages "from the ground up", so to speak, before things will start working again. You might try a command like this (untested):

```
cabal install --reinstall `ghc-pkg list --user | grep '^  '`
```

This lists all the packages in your local (user) database and asks cabal to reinstall them all.

Comment: why not `cabal install --reinstall world`?

Comment: @dflemstr I believe `cabal install --reinstall world` is not officially condoned. Perhaps this is in part because it does not fix version numbers (as my proposed command does).